# Why aren't my javascript checkboxes working?

Tags: javascript

```
accessoryChoices = document.getElementsByName("accessories");
var accessoriesTotal;
function PressThis()
{

if (accessoryChoices[0].checked)
{
   accessoriesTotal = 56.45;


}

if (accessoryChoices[1].checked)
{
   accessoriesTotal += 115.35;

}

if (accessoryChoices[2].checked)
{
   accessoriesTotal += (7.25);

}
else 
{
   accessoriesTotal= 5.66;

}
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= accessoriesTotal;
return;
}
```

I can't seem to display the proper value. If I press all the buttons together then they add up, but if I press the first button it goes to 0. If I press the bottom buttons they add up, but If press the last button first then it goes to NaN.

Comment: Well you never declare `accessoriesTotal` with a  value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set accessoriesTotal with a  value so you add undefined with a number.

```
function PressThis() {
    var accessoriesTotal = 0;  //<--set it to zero
```

And  am not sure that else is what you really want. If they do not select the last one, it will set everything to 5.66. Is that what you want or should it be `+=`?

---

Based on your comment your code should be

```
function PressThis() {
    var accessoriesTotal = 0;
    if (accessoryChoices[0].checked) {
        accessoriesTotal += 56.45;
    }
    if (accessoryChoices[1].checked) {
        accessoriesTotal += 115.35;
    }
    if (accessoryChoices[2].checked) {
        accessoriesTotal += 7.25;
    }

    if (accessoriesTotal===0) {  // or if (!accessoryChoices[0].checked && !accessoryChoices[1].checked && !accessoryChoices[2].checked) {
       accessoriesTotal= 5.66;
    }

    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= accessoriesTotal;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I thought I only had to declare it?

Comment: And it is `undefined` when you declare it. So declare it with a value.

Comment: I tried that but, it only shows the else statement when I click the first button.

Comment: Because it is doing exactly what you told it to do. Your code says if the last one is not checked, than it needs to be 5.66. You do not say it should add 5.66 to the running total.

Comment: Well, this is a small snippet of my bigger project. I have everything working expect the check boxes. This sample is one I created separately  in order to see what is going wrong. I want the answer to be 5.66 if nothing is chosen between the three checkboxes. I apologize if I sound ignorant.

Comment: Your code only says if the last one is not selected, not is all are not selected.